# Java path errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and this is my code:

```
public class MessAround {

static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello world example");

    }

}
```

For some reason I am encountering problems with this code and I do not know why since I am using an appropriate environment with a library.

**Screenshot of problems:**
[image: Photo of Eclipse]

**My question:**  If I am using a JRE and have the JDK, what am I doing wrong to encounter these simple problems?

Comment: Right click your project, Build Path -> Configure Build Path, check for any red X. It looks like you've added OSGI as a dependency but Eclipse can't find it.

Comment: OT, but you'll need public static void main. Note that public is important

Comment: I cannot see any red X's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you your main method can not non public:

```
class MessAround {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

Secondly, it seems that you do not have your JDK set in Eclipse, you should go to

`Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's` tab and select in your classpath the JRE.

Comment: Main cannot be void? I suppose you meant it cannot be non-public.